# MobileIron App Distribution Requirements

Tags: mobile, iron, mobileiron

I'm developing an in-house app for a company which distributes their apps via MobileIron to their iPads. Until now they distributed only apps from the Appstore. I sent them an IPA file, but they are not able to install it. Does anybody know what the requirements are I have to meet to export an MobileIron compatible app? I have a standard developer account. I tried to reach out to MobileIron support but it was not this helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Greg,
if the company wants to distribute the app direct from their own MobileIron App store (and not only featuring an AppStore app) you need to sign it with a certificate and provisioning profile from an Apple Enterprise Developer Account for In-House-Distribution. The standard developer account is only useful for AppStore deployment or the configured developer & testing devices.

Hope that helps.
Jago